# Batch file not executing

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I have created a batch file the runs the follow commands:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave  "C:\Users\Bloomberg\R\ERVOL.R"
```

When I enter this command into the command prompt, it executes the program exactly the way I would expect. However, when I double click on the .bat file, the command prompt pops up for a split second, closes, and the program does not execute.

How can I get the .bat file to execute properly?

Comment: When you run it from the command prompt, are you in a particular directory?  You may need to change to that folder within your batch file.

Comment: perhaps.. when i run in the command prompt, the directory is C:\Users\Bloomberg>. should i first cd to C:\>?

Comment: I just tried running the contents of the batch file when the directory is different in the command prompt and it didn't make a difference in performance. Still runs just fine.

Comment: Well, I don't know what is wrong with this issue, but I found a work-around. my batch file now simply changes directory and then uses the "Rscript" command.

Comment: Stu, since you found the solution yourself, you can post a more detailed answer containing the line in the batch file, and accept your own answer.  Sounds like it was a combination of changing the directory and using rscript.

Answer (score 0):

this may be caused by a small bug in the path:

> C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\R.exe

try putting an underscore so that it looks like this:

> C:\Program_Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\R.exe